# How can an answer end up in the First Answer Queue multiple times?

Tags: bug, review-queues, first-answers

I just noticed [an answer](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/425/38) that has been in the First Answers Queue twice. I have not seen this on other sites such as Stack Overflow before. Why is this site able to have First Answers enter the Queue multiple times?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem related to this site; I have reported it on Meta Stack Exchange a while ago: [Why did this answer get three First Answer review queue items?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370881/295232). It *looks* to have been triggered by an edit by the author, but it's definitely a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).